# Haskell Snap Framework - Type mismatch ByteString / Maybe ByteString

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I am fairly new to Haskell and Snap and I am working through my own project for a small web forum using snap. The problem I am having is in understanding the conflict and how to resolve for the following code.

```
handleCategoryAdd :: H ()
handleCategoryAdd = method POST (withLoggedInUser go)
  where
    go user = do
      bs <- getParam "categoryName"
      cN <- B.unpack $ Just bs
      cD <- getParam "categoryDesc"
      cT <- getCurrentTime
      return (Db.saveCategory (Db.Category 1 cN cT "1" ))
      redirect "/"
```

Gives me a type mismatch error as follows:

```
src\Site.hs:118:22:
    Couldn't match expected type `ByteString'
                with actual type `Maybe ByteString'
    In the first argument of `unpack', namely `bs'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: cN <- unpack bs
    In the expression:
      do { bs <- getParam "categoryName";
           cN <- unpack bs;
           cD <- getParam "categoryDesc";
           cT <- getCurrentTime;
           .... }
```

Any advice to clear up the confusion would be much appreciated, I have been searching for some way to unwrap the maybe and just retrieve the bytestring but have been unsuccessful.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Just` is a constructer for the type `Maybe a`.  `getParam`, i'm pretty sure, returns `Snap Maybe Bytestring` so `bs` is of type `Maybe Bytestring`.  When you say `Just bs` you then would have `Maybe (Maybe Bytestring)` which is clearly what you don't want.  You are looking for `fromJust :: Maybe a -> a`  but this function is dangerous because you haven't checked if `getParam` has even succeeded and there is an input on on the html page with that name.

What you should do is use cases or `>>=`.

Something like

```
bs <- getParam "categoryName"
case bs of
   Nothing -> writeBS "failed"
   Just b  -> do
      let unpacked = B.unpack b
      -- ... Do more stuff
```

**EDIT**

It depends what you are trying to do.  Bind can be useful and so can `liftM`, `lifM2`, `liftM3`, etc.

In your case you may want liftM2.  I don't know what your types are but I'll give a very simple example.  Save you have have those 2 Bytestrings you could do something like this.

```
bs1 <- getParam "one"
bs2 <- getParam "two"

case (liftM2 append bs1 bs2) of
   Nothing -> writeBS "Failed"
   Just b  -> writeBS b
```

Comment: how would you use >>= in this case??

Answer (score 1):

A nice way of extracting a value from a `Maybe a` type is to use the `fromMaybe` function from the `Data.Maybe` module. It's useful if you have a default value to use in the case of a `Nothing` value in the `Maybe`.

I will present an example in the IO monad rather than some Snap monad, in order to avoid pulling in the Snap libraries for the demo code to work, but it should work the same (aside from type signature changes) as long as the handler is in the same monad as the `getParam` actions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Data.Maybe
import           Data.ByteString.Char8 (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

getParam1, getParam2 :: IO (Maybe ByteString)
getParam1 = return $ Just "Hello"
getParam2 = return $ Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = do
   str1 <- getParam1 >>= return . fromMaybe "No value"
   str2 <- getParam2 >>= return . fromMaybe "No value"

   B.putStrLn str1
   B.putStrLn str2
```

Since `getParam1` and `getParam2` are `IO (Maybe ByteString)`, we know we need to use a monadic action to get at the `Maybe ByteString` value inside.

By looking at the type signature of `>>=`, which is `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, we can set type `a` to be `Maybe ByteString` and type `b` to be `IO ByteString`, which means we are looking to apply the bind with these specific types:

```
-- (Type of getParam1 >>= Type of our function to supply)    -> Desired type 
IO (Maybe ByteString) -> (Maybe ByteString -> IO ByteString) -> IO ByteString
```

With that in mind, we can look at the type of `fromMaybe`:

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
```

We can partially apply fromMaybe with a default ByteString and get:

```
fromMaybe "No value" :: Maybe ByteString -> ByteString
```

Now we compose that function with `return` to put the `ByteString` back in `IO`:

```
return . fromMaybe "No value" :: Maybe ByteString -> IO ByteString
```

This is the type we need to use `>>=` on the result of `getParam1`.

Since we are in a `do` block in the `IO` monad, we can extract the `ByteString` for further use using the `<-` binding arrow syntax:

```
str1 <- getParam1 >>= return . fromMaybe "No value"
```

At this point, you have a pure `ByteString` in `str1` to use as you see fit in the `do` block.

Hopefully you find this explanation helpful!